# Want to get the Dataset to branch1 via branch2 in Github

Tags: git, github, github-actions, github-api

I have build the data in branch1 and i merged the code in to branch2,

- now i am buidling the branch2 Dataset in branch 2, now i have location1 in branch1 and location2
- in branch2, now i want to have location1 and location2 both the location in branch2

So basically location1 dataset in branch1 i want to read via branch2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.